# void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

when i am using radio group on old android support v4 , it will run properly.But When i am using latest android support v4 then i am getting this issue. it crashed on setOnCheckedChangeListener. please help me .

```
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172): Process: com.example.test, PID: 6172
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
01-08 15:04:31.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6172):     ... 10 more
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    RadioGroup rg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);  // getting null

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> "+rg);
            }
        });
    }
}

///--------------------------------------------------------

<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

</RadioGroup>

Please any one help me to resolve this error plz....
Thanks in advance
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_radiogroup_control.htm
please refer this

Answer (score 0):

Actually I copied your code and build, run it without any problem.

So I think you may give more information about your code? For instance, you may give the whole code about your MainActivity.java include the import part.

There are something different in my copied code which can run well. I use the Android Studio 2.0, when I paste you code, I make some change:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
...
```

There are two different place which I changed. 
One is the 'MainActivity extends from *AppCompatActivity* instead of *Activity*.'

I'm new at Android, so I didn't know why in studio it use this way...

Second one is the '*RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()* instead of *OnCheckedChangeListener()*'

It's also by studio's suggest to modify it.

Wish my idea can help you.
And sorry for my poor English...*(:зゝ∠)*